# Simple C++ Inclusive Calculator Code Review

Tags: c++

C++ newbie here. Anything wrong or complicated with this code? The main question I have is whether I can use v1 and v2 inside while (val <= v2)?

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    int sum = 0, val = v1;

    while (val <= v2)
    {
        sum += val;
        ++ val;
    }
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " through " << v2 << " inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. You can use v1 and v2 inside while, I don't think you want to though.

Comment: Well firstly you should know that it's possible to do that calculation without looping. `n*(n+1)/2` gives you the triangle numbers. Subtract the lower from the upper and you're good. As for your scope question, as long as you're within the same `{}` brackets as you declared the variable within, you're good (with some exceptions for implicit `{}`s).

Comment: To make it so that you do not have to say `std::cout` or `std::cin` every time, why don't you put between the `#include <iostream>` and the `int main()` lines the statement `using namespace std` so you only have to type in `cout` or `cin` without the prefix?

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome polluting the global Namespace is not always a good idea. Most times it is better to explicitly use the namespace `std` than importing all names.

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome: Because `using namespace` is evil? How is avoiding typing a few charactes worth not making it less clear that you are using standard library functionality (instead of some user defined stuff with the same name)?

Comment: should maybe be moved to codereview...

Comment: @Grizzly I get what you're saying. It's just something I've grown to use more often than not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, they're local variables in `main()` so they're in scope until `main()` returns (i. e. the whole lifetime of the program).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. The statement inside the `while`-loop needs to evaluate to a boolean expression, i.e. `true` or `false`. And as you can state that either it is true that `val <= v2` or not, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, and and a boolean expression either evalutes to `true == >=1` or `false == 0`. So this is okay

Comment: This is C++! This is not C here. And in C++ there is a `bool`, implicitly converting to `int` if necessary. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4dy80a(v=vs.110).aspx).